# How can I document a property defined with Object.defineProperties() in WebStorm (JSDoc)

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jsdoc, yuidoc

Let's say I define a property with `Object.defineProperties()`. If I try to specify the type of this property with a JSDoc comment, WebStorm gives me a warning.

Here is an example:

```
Object.defineProperties(obj, {

    /**
     * @type {String}
     */
    example: { get: function() { return 'example'; } }
}
```

This will give me the following WebStorm warning: *Initializer type {get: Function} is not assignable to variable type String*.

If I switch to the following, the warning goes away but the generated documentation does not say that a "string" is expected:

```
Object.defineProperties(obj, {

    /**
     * @type {get: Function}
     */
    example: { get: function() { return 'example'; } }
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this ?

Comment: I'm not an expert here, but could you just document it elsewhere as a property on `obj` with `@property {string} example`?

Comment: @apsillers If I move the whole comment block outside Object.defineProperties() the warning goes away. However, I would much prefer to have the comment right above where the property is defined. Isn't that possible ?